# I see uncaught TypeError when I use timepicker

Tags: jquery, laravel, timepicker

I tested timepicker on my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/bxXvGb) and it works just fine.

Now, I am trying to do the same in my laravel site via cdn, but for some reason I see the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
```

If I inspect the site, I can clearly see both the stylesheet and javascript links being loaded as you can see in the image  below:

[image]

I had initially tried via npm, but had no success on that either.

It is weird that I can use Datetimepicker, but cannot use timepicker cause I assume it is done the same way.

Anything I could have possibly done wrong?

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your Laravel site?

Comment: @Michael Hurley Yes I ave jquery loading first via webpack

Comment: unable to see jquery included in your code

Comment: The jquery is compiled to the libs.js file using webpack

Comment: Where do you call the `.$(...).timepicker` though? Some more information would come a long way

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available in your screenshot. You have not included **jquery** in your project. Another issue is you have included CDN but CDN link is not valid at all. it does not have **http** or **https**. Try to fix them. before adding javascript file in your project be sure that you have added **jquery** at first and other **js** files one by one like below

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTable.min.js"></script>
```

You should see below-marked screenshot to see the errors in your project

[image]